# How to read word(or character) on txt file from the last word to the first word in python?

Tags: python

Example: I have a file as :
filename1 = "I am a student" (inside filename1 have I am a student )

```
f = open(filename1)
string = f.read()
spl = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.](?!\d)',string)
f.close
```

print spl will show:
I am a student , but I need the result as [student a am I]
could you answer me please...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside: `f.close` is missing `()` at the end and so the method isn't actually called.  It's a good habit to get into writing `with open(filename1) as f:` instead and indenting the next two lines like a for loop -- that idiom will automatically close the file for you when you're done with it, without any need for an explicit `close`.

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the list with a [martian smiley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695416/190597):

```
spl = spl[::-1]
```

Or, if you just need an iterator:

```
spl = reversed(spl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str=['im a student','im a teacher']
list=[]
for x in str:
   new=""
   for y in [x for x in reversed(x.split())]:
       new+=y
       new+=' '
   list.append(new)

print list // ['student a im ', 'teacher a im ']
```

Comment: `list` and `str` are both the names of builtins, so shadowing those names with user-defined variables should generally be avoided as it leads to confusion.  That's especially true here, where your `str` isn't a string but a list of strings.

Comment: Yes,I accept your point.But Here i meant to use list instead of reading from a file since reading a line from a file is similar to  read a string from a list. This is just I have made an example to make it simple and clear in understanding.